# how to fix my UI button which freezes when I tap it?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

Im using Xcode 5.0.2, Im still learning how to code in iOS. Any help would truly be appreciated here's my code.

```
- (IBAction)btnMenuTapped:(id)sender
{
    if (self.popoverController)
    {
        [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        self.popoverController = nil;
    }
    else
    {
        MainMenuViewController *contentViewController = [[MainMenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainMenuViewController" bundle:nil];
        contentViewController.delegate = self;

        self.popoverController = [[WEPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:contentViewController];

        self.popoverController.delegate = self;
        self.popoverController.popoverContentSize = contentViewController.view.frame.size;

        [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:[sender frame]
                                                inView:self.view
                              permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown
                                              animated:YES];

    }
}

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <LoginDelegate,WEPopoverParentView,PopoverControllerDelegate,MainMenuDelegate,MKMapViewDelegate,UIActionSheetDelegate,UIAccelerometerDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, NSObject>
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate;
    IBOutlet MKMapView *userMap;
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;

}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *speedView;
@property(nonatomic) int speedCount;
@property (nonatomic,retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (nonatomic, strong) WEPopoverController *popoverController;

+ (NSString *) speedToMPH: (float) value;


- (IBAction)btnMenuTapped:(id)sender;

@end
```

But this line of code is where my app freezes

```
self.popoverController.popoverContentSize = contentViewController.view.frame.size;
```

here a picture of the button I'm trying to click on
[image: menu button]

and this is what I get in the debug area

self    MainViewController *    0x1656d100  0x1656d100
contentViewController   MainMenuViewController *    0x1864eef0  0x1864eef0

Answer (score 0):

Before the MainMenuViewController presents, the view property of your view controller is nil. So when you try to retrieve its view.frame.size it crashes. Try giving pre-defined bounds.

For instance:

```
 self.popoverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 500);
```

Comment: could you elaborate on that please?

Comment: and also you do not have to set popoverContentSize you already passed contentviewcontroller while initializing popover controller. Thus, it will create your popover controller as it fits to your contentviewcontroller

Comment: I tried this method and i still get the same result. It is continuing to freeze what else could it possibly be?